# Copy file from cron job's pod to local directory in AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cronjob

I have created a cron job which runs every 60 min. In the job's container I have mounted emptyDir volume as detailed-logs. In my container I am writing a csv file at path `detailed-logs\logs.csv`.

I am trying to copy this file from pod to local machine using `kubectl cp podname:detailed-logs\logs.csv \k8slogs\logs.csv` but it throws the error:

> path "detailed-logs\logs.csv" not found (no such file or directory).

Once job runs successfully, pod created by job goes to `completed` state, is this can be a issue?

Answer (score 0):

The file you are referring to is not going to persist once your pod completes running. What you can do is make a backup of the file when the cron job is running. The two solutions I can suggest are either attach a persistent volume to the job pod, or to upload the file somewhere while running the job.

**USE A PERSISTENT VOLUME**

Here you can create a PV through a quick `readWriteOnce` Persistent Volume Claim:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Then you can mount it onto the pod using the following:

```
      ...
        volumeMounts:
        - name: persistent-storage
          mountPath: /detailed-logs
      volumes:
      - name: persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: my-pvc
      ...
```

**UPLOAD FILE**

The way I do it is run the job in a container that has `aws-cli` installed, and then store my file on AWS S3, you can choose another platform:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: backup-sh
data:
  backup.sh: |-
    #!/bin/bash
    aws s3 cp /myText.txt s3://bucketName/
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: s3-backup
spec:
  schedule: "0 0 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: aws-kubectl
            image: expert360/kubectl-awscli:v1.11.2
            env:
            - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: s3-creds
                  key: access-key-id
            - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: s3-creds
                  key: secret-access-key
            command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
            args: ["sh /backup.sh"]
            volumeMounts:
            - name: backup-sh
              mountPath: /backup.sh
              readOnly: true
              subPath: backup.sh
          volumes:
          - name: backup-sh
            configMap:
              name: backup-sh
          restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: i can't use persisted volume or external storage as suggested. Is there any way to use non persisted volume which i can use? Cron job keeps the previous jobs history, so is there any volume associated with it.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) for using a hostPath volume. Quoting from the text, "A hostPath volume mounts a file or directory from the host node’s filesystem into your Pod." @Tarun